# How do I use two mouse press functions in python?

Tags: python

First scene with first mouse press

[image]

That first onMousePress function makes the background change.

Second scene with second mouse press

[image]

This second onMousePress function is planned to make the barrels disappear but it just kind of replaces the first onMousePress and makes it so that's the only one that works. Also ignore the 2 and the fact that it actually makes a rectangle, the 2 made it not work so I can click on the future tp and the rect is for testing purposes

Comment: read [ask], review the [tour] and provide a [mre] as text

Answer (score 0):

You can set flag of first click and some small wait time. If the event is triggered second time it is double click, otherwise it is single click when time runs out. You need to set wait time in parallel thread or use something like timer. And don't forget to reset your flag everytime.